# Poltergeist Rspec If-None-Match If-Modified-Since headers

Tags: capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have a feature spec that makes two visit requests to the same url. The expected behavior is that the second request should return a 304. This is not happening however. I have set the phantomjs_options: ['--disk-cache=true'] but that does not seem to have the desired effect. Is there some other setting that needs to be configured to use If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since headers?

An example below:

```
visit "/p/:id"
page.driver.status_code.should eq 200
visit "/p/:id"
page.driver.status_code.should eq 304
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this. I'd suggest testing it using only PhantomJS to see if you can replicate the issue there - if so file a bug against PhantomJS.